# Do testers' devices need to be registered under (Provision profile)Provisioned Device for testing Ad-Hoc iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am new in iOS development world. Currently, I'm trying to export my app for some users to test. I do not want to upload to the store first, so I'd export my app as Ad-Hoc Deployment. After that, I uploaded my myApp.ipa to Diawi to generate link for distribution. But two kind of results I got:

> Note: Both devices are iPhone 6, both iOS v9.3.2.

1. Device 1: **Successful**
2. Device 2: **Not Successful**

   - They able to download but once the circle is completed. This message prompted. No matter how many times they tested, the result still the same.
     [Unsuccessfull Message Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGn3b.png)

I do not understand what is happening. Tested in many devices, some successfully downloaded, but some not. Should I register each of them in the application under **Provisioned Devices**? If ***yes***, is there any other way to distribute the app without needing to register them? If ***no***, what actually I need to do to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ad-hoc provisioning profile must include a device's UDID before that device can use apps signed with that profile's certificate.  You can always upload the App Store and enable testing, without submitting for review.

Comment: Yes, as @Avi point it out, you should use TestFlight. It's really easier to use ;)

Comment: @Avi so do I have any method to get users' device's UDID automatically? And, do you mean that when i upload the app to store, I have the option not to publish instead, I can choose for testing? Then where can the users download the app?

Comment: @RomOne i thought of that too but, i wanted to include link in the email and let user directly click on the link to download. Because the target users now are non-tech people.. so I thought it might be easier and quick for them to directly download the apps once they receive my distribution email.

Comment: You are also right, many users miss the email from itunesconnect inviting them to the beta test. That would be great if Apple let us custom that email.

Comment: @RomOne yaya...wish that Apple can let us export an Ad-Hoc app by generating a link and distribute to our beta tester. So, any other idea you have?

Answer (score 0):

**Most common causes of this issue:**

- Device storage is full
- The provisioning profile is a developer provisioning profile
- The ad hoc distribution provisioning profile is corrupted and the
  device is having an issue with it.
- The device was restored from a backup and is causing a conflict for
  over-the-air distribution
- There was a network timeout
- Architecture settings of the build and the device are incompatible (
  can sometimes happen when "Build Active Architecture Only" is on when
  building).
- Not Using Mobile Safari.
- Check also "iOS Deployment Target"

**To find out the exact cause of this issue:**

- Connect the device with iMac.
- Open Organizer then choose devices.
- Choose your Connected device from sidebar.
- Choose Console inside the chosen device.
- Now install the app it will show the exact cause of problem

I think this is helpfull for you.

Comment: The points above (under the "Most common causes of this issue") already been checked. They are not the cause. The guidance under the "To find out the exact cause of this issue" are very difficult for me as I couldn't ask every testers come to my place and connect their devices to my mac. Btw, thanks for the suggestion. :)